# Extract JSON values from remote api with Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, api, sinatra

I'm trying to grab some data from last.fm and use it in a simple sinatra app. I've worked out how to open the document but having issues extracting the data in ruby here is the first list of the API data I'd like to grab the name:

> {"similarartists":{"artist":[{"name":"Sonny & Cher"}]}

This is just an extract of the return, I'm using this in my rb file:

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'

data = JSON.parse(open("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist=editors&api_key=xxx&format=json").read)

puts data["similarartists"]["artist"]["name"]
```

It doesn't seem to be working I get can't convert String into Integer (TypeError) on ruby 1.9.3 but the name in the JSON isn't an integer? If I just put the following:

```
puts data["similarartists"]["artist"]
```

It returns the whole thing, but I want to grab inside of that and get the name.

```
"name"=>"Interpol"
```

I don't understand why it would complain about integers when the name is a string? Hope someone can help me!

Comment: What does `data` look like before you try to access `data['similarartists']['artist']['name']`? Are you sure you are getting that extact JSON stored in `data`?

Comment: I've just done a puts data and here is a snippet of the beginning {"similarartists"=>{"artist"=>[{"name"=>"Interpol", "mbid"=>"b23e8a63-8f47-4882-b

Comment: Are you missing a `"` at the end of the mbid? wish I could test this but I don't have a Last.FM API key.

Comment: That's correct the output is very long so I just sent the first line so you can see, it's just the name I'm after. I just wanted to show that the name doesn't contain any integers?

Comment: Your structure you put here in the comments suggests the problem is artist is an array of artists so the problem is you are trying to directly take `['name']` but that is not an integer index, which is what ruby is telling you. It should be `data['similarartists']['artist'][0]['name']`

Comment: My goodness! Thank you Alex.. please put your solution below so I can accept?

Comment: Aww I was just typing out that solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments thread, the issue is a misunderstanding of the structure of the data returned from the API call.

The exact issue was the structure had an array of artists under the artist key so to get at the name you need to do:
 `data['similarartists']['artist'][0]['name']`

Note though that you should only do that if you are sure there will only be one artist. The nature of the return data suggests that won't always be the case so you might be better off pulling all names depending on your use doing something like:
`data['similarartists']['artist'].map {|a| a['name']}.join(',')`

That will join all of the artist names together comma separated.

In the future, you can track this issue down by looking at the full structure of the return data and making sure you see the correct structure. The docs on the API may indicate some help here too.

You also might check if someone has made a gem for accessing the API. Often a gem will up-level some of this raw output and give you a nice object to work with. I suggest searching GitHub for a last.fm gem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to access an Array with the index `"name"`, Ruby tries to convert this to an Integer and fails which results in the Error message you are seeing.

If you test the `class` of `data["similarartists"]["artist"].class` you will see that it returns `Array`. So basically what is happening is that the `JSON.parse()` called created as the value of `data["similarartists"]["artist"]` an Array of Hashes. To access all of the artist names you can simply iterate through this array:

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'

data = JSON.parse(open("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist=editors&api_key=29da5a0e01ca2d1524cac596d5462d67&format=jso\
n").read)


# iterate through the Array of returned artists and print their names                                                                                 
data["similarartists"]["artist"].each do |artist|
  puts artist["name"]
end

# output
# Interpol
# White Lies
# The Cinematics
# Smith & Burrows
# The National
# Julian Plenti
# She Wants Revenge
# etc ...
```

If you only want the *first* entry for Interpol you can just use index `[0]`:

```
puts data["similarartists"]["artist"][0]["name"]
```